# How to make a SharePoint 2013 "yes/no" list field to be displayed as a checkbox during inline editing?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a "yes/no" field in a SharePoint 2013 list. In a default list view I can click "edit" link and get to inline editing of the list. In this case I can edit the "yes/no" field via a dropdown with values "yes" and "no". Like so:

[image]

But in my solution I have lots of records that must be clicked through by users as quickly as possible. And a checkbox is more convenient for this, but not a dropdown.

So is there any way (with or without custom development) to display a checkbox instead of a dropdown in inline editing mode? Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Alvmad. Nice article, but it's more about trade-offs in a particular type of a SharePoint 2013 list.

I asked MSDN forum about the problem and got awesome links to a kind of developer reference for "Quick Edit" mode customizations in SharePoint 2013: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ea0ec86-b6ba-49cd-afaa-3e1b7b5ba3ec/how-to-make-a-yesno-field-to-be-displayed-as-a-checkbox-during-inline-editing

Answer (score 3):

This is a good and a complex question. The only way I think you can do this is via JQuery changing the controls on document.ready or using the JSLink of the list like Tobias Zimergren does in [his post](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013) and then capturing the ajax that is firing after you modify something

Within your function `ConvertToCheckBox(ctx)` you should render an input check instead of the Yes/no Combo.

The file `hierarchytaskslist.js` within `15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` folder actually converts Yes/no in checkbox. Check it [here](http://www.estruyf.be/blog/applying-js-link-on-task-lists-breaks-the-default-rendering-of-the-checkboxes/)